# CSS style not applies for custom class

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am developping ASP.NET MVC5 SPA. I have view called `_Home` and `Site.css` that is used to manage styles of `_Home`. In `_Home.cshtml` I have custom class `col-contacts`. Here full `_Home.cshtml` code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="col-contacts">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            <p>Some text on which background should be applied</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <h2>Get more libraries</h2>
        <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is code from `Site.css`.

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.col-contacts {
    border-style: solid;
    border: 2px;
    border-color: #000000;
}
```

But `css` style is not applied

[image]

Comment: Did you add the reference to your `CSS` file in the master page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `border-width: 2px;` instead of the `border: 2px;` or combine all three properties under the shorthand ... like so `border: #000000 solid 2px;`

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mturjak/Lqygtuy0/)